# Installing cURL on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, php

Am trying to install cURL on my ubuntu server using the command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

However i get the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-curl: Depends: phpapi-20060613+lfs
Depends: php5-common (= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.5) but 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am running **PHP Version 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1** on my server.

When I try this command

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

I get the following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libcurl3-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.18.2-8ubuntu4.1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libcurl3-dev has no installation candidate
root@server:~# sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libcurl3-dev is a virtual package provided by:
  libcurl4-openssl-dev 7.18.2-8ubuntu4.1
You should explicitly select one to install.
E: Package libcurl3-dev has no installation candidate
```

Whats the issue? I need to get curl up and running.

Comment: Did you do some pinning to get dotdeb to work?  You will need to get curl from the same repo as php.

Comment: Pinning? Please explain. The php/apache installation works just fine for quite sometime now and its only recently that I need cURL for a particular app.

Comment: Post the output of these commands `apt-cache policy php5-common`, `apt-cache policy php5-curl`, `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, and `cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/*`.

Comment: For the record DOTDEB is not designed to be used with Ubuntu.  It may work in some conditions, it is certainly not supported.  You may have just reached a point where what you want is simply impossible with that set of packages.

Comment: I got it working by changing my sources.Thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
Depends: php5-common (= 5.2.6.dfsg.1-3ubuntu4.5) but 5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1 is to be installed
```

apt is not comfortable with your **5.3.2-0.dotdeb.1** so it misses **php5-common**.

fix your php version. easiest way should be to install **php5-common** regularly over apt and try again.

Comment: If he does that, he will almost certainly break his PHP installation, or possibly just force it to revert back to 5.2.6 instead of 5.3.2.

Comment: As you wrote, dotdeb isn't thought for ubuntu. So the best way would be to get back to start by removing it and using the main apt repos. Don't know why this should break everything...